# Trouble displaying an interval with close bounds in R

Tags: r, set, digits

I am using the `sets` package in `R` to try to create a closed interval with an upper bound of one and a lower bound that is quite near to one.  The problem is that I am getting some strange behaviour for the interval.  When called it displays as a singleton set containing only the lower bound, but when I ask for the minimum or maximum values in the interval it gives me the correct values.  When I look at the structure of the interval it shows both of the bounds as one.

```
library(sets)
options(digits = 15)

#Set lower bound and interval
L <- 0.999999999989428
INT <- sets::interval(l = L, r = 1, bounds = 'closed')

#Print interval and show details
INT
{0.999999999989428}

min(INT)
[1] 0.999999999989428

max(INT)
[1] 1

str(INT)
List of 1
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ l : num 1
  ..$ r : num 1
  ..$ lc: logi TRUE
  ..$ rc: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "domain")= chr "R"
```

I would like to be able to construct intervals of this kind, with lower bounds that are close to one.  I need them to print correctly, as a closed interval showing the correct lower and upper bound.  Although not super important, ideally I would also like the structure call to show the correct bounds.

**Question:** Is there some way to ensure that the interval will print and show its structure with the correct bounds?  If not, is this a problem with the `sets` package, or is it some deeper limitation on numbers close to one in `R`?

Comment: Hi Ben, I worked out the problem, please see my edit below

Answer (score 1):

If you read the help article for `str()` you will see that the default number of decimals to print (digits.d) is 3. Setting `options(digits = 15)` does not change the default within `str()`. All you have to do is change the number of digits in the function args:

```
str(INT,digits.d=15)
List of 1
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ l : num 0.999999999989428
  ..$ r : num 1
  ..$ lc: logi TRUE
  ..$ rc: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "domain")= chr "R"
```

**EDIT:**
This took a bit of digging. The issue was deep in hidden code. Your interval was always constructed correctly but the printing mechanism to see the structure was limited to a tolerance of 1.05719877298024e-11 in the `all.equal` function, and you wanted 10^-15.This demonstrates the issue:

```
##code thinks that 0.999999999989428 = 1 as the tolerance is to high
all.equal(L, 1)
[1] TRUE

##you are unable to set the tolerance to your required level
all.equal(L, 1,tolerance = 10^-15)
[1] "Mean relative difference: 1.05719877298024e-11"
```

To get around this I have modified the hidden code to use the logical operator `==` instead of  `all.equal()`. See here that `==` can identify that the values are different:

```
L==1
[1] FALSE
```

Run this line first to modify the hidden code and then the interval will print as you require:

```
as.character.interval <-
  function(x, ...)
  {
    if (length.interval(x) < 1L)
      return("{}")

    if (interval_is_uncountable(x)) {
      bounds <- if (sets_options("openbounds") == "][")
        c("]", "[", "[", "]")
      else
        c("(", "[", ")", "]")

      ## merge adjacent degenerate intervals into sets
      .merge = function(x, y) {
        i = length(x)
        X <- x[[i]]
        Y <- y[[1]]
        if ((is.set(X) || isTRUE(X$l == X$r)) &&
            isTRUE(all.equal(Y$l, Y$r))) {
          if (!is.set(X)) X <- set(X$l)
          c(x[-i], list(c(X, Y$l)))
        } else
          c(x, y)
      }
      l <- Reduce(.merge, lapply(unclass(x), list))

      ## format individual interval
      .format <- function(x) {
        if (is.set(x))
          format(x)
        else if (isTRUE(x$l == x$r))
          paste("{", as.character(x$l), "}", sep = "")
        else
          paste(bounds[1 + x$lc], x$l, ", ", x$r,
                bounds[3 + x$rc], sep = "")
      }

      paste(sapply(unclass(l), .format), collapse = " U ")

    } else {
      .format <- function(x)
        if (x$l == x$r) x$l else paste(x$l, "..", x$r, sep = "")
      paste(sapply(unclass(x), .format), collapse = ", ")
    }
  }
```

Now your interval will print correctly:

```
INT
[0.999999999989428, 1]
```